# hashmap key value in java

Tags: java, hashmap

i have 2 objects created as

```
final VideoObj v1 = new VideoObj("A", 2000, "B");
final VideoObj v1copy = new VideoObj("A", 2000, "B");
```

i an using a hash map as below

```
private final Map<Video, Record> _data = _data = new HashMap<Video, Record>();
```

is v1 is added to Video record is incermented by 1 whihc is in the Record class,

how does the hash map know this is the same key, because i added v1 1st and the record was 1 then i added v1copy then the record is 2. why is it becoming 2 instead of added a new one for v1copy

please help me with this
thanks

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why.

Comment: You either need to give a clear description of the problem or proper, relevant code.  Usually both.  Never neither.  But from the little I understood of your post it seems like VideoObj is properly implementing `hashCode` and `equals` and so since `v1` and `v1copy` are composed of identical data they are treated as equal keys.  If you don't want this use an `IdentityHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Is it `Video` or `VideoObj`? Why is there `_data = _data = ...` in that last line? It's important to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even sure what you're asking, does this explanation help at all?

`HashMap`s compare objects based on the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, by default these check object identity, so v1 and v1copy won't be treated as identical unless you override the `hashCode()` method in class `VideoObj`.

Comment: Video is an interface and Video Obj implements it.

Comment: private final Map<Video, Record> _data = new HashMap<Video, Record>();

Answer (score 1):

Did you override equals() method in VideoObj class? And does it check for equality based one the three parameters constructor takes? You might want to check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: public interface Video extends Comparable<Video> { 
 public String director(); 
 public String title();
 public int year();
public boolean equals(Object thatObject);
 
 public int hashCode();
 public int compareTo(Video that);
 public String toString();
}